# Importing normal custom js file throwing error Nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a `constants.js` file in my root directory of the **Nuxt** application. This file contains constant variables that are exported using `module.exports.<var_name>`.

When this file is imported in my `/pages/index.vue` as

`import { feature1, feature2, feature3, news } from '../constants';`
It is throwing an error as below:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'feature1' of undefined
    at Module.eval (constants.js?c4f5:1)
    at eval (constants.js:111)
    at Module../constants.js (pages_index.js:283)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:796)
```

**constants.js :-**

```
module.exports.feature1 = [...];
module.exports.feature2 = [...];
...
```

**index.vue:-**

```
import { feature1, feature2, feature3, news } from '../constants';
export default {
 data() {
      return {
        newsList: news,
        isMobile: false,
        featuresList1: feature1,
        featuresList2: feature2,
        featuresList3: feature3,
        showAll: false
      };
    }
}
```

**NOTE- This error is not coming once you build and deploy to production. Weird.**

Hitting my head around. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it works just fine for me but i have changed one thing

in your `index.vue` instead of importing like `../constants` import like `~/routeToLocation`

my code is:

**test.js**

```
module.exports.feature1 = 'this is a test'
```

**index.vue**

```
import { feature1 } from '~/test'
export default {
data() {
    return {
      test: feature1,
           }
       }
}
```

and the value of test is "this is a test"

PS: i put my `test.js` file next to the `nuxt.config.js`

hope it works!

Comment: I have changed the import like you have suggested `~/constants` which is of course at my root project directory, next to `nuxt.config.js`. But it didn't worked!